# What is the exact format and size of Image() object?

Tags: opencv, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, camera, image-raw

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot figure out what is the exact format of the sensor_msg Image() file. When I issue the command:

```
rostopic echo /camera/image_raw
```

I get a massive output consisting of thousands of numbers in an array. However, when I look up the documentation, there is supposed to be a heading, height, width, etc and the actual data. I have never been able to find the header or any other parameter from the output. I also cannot figure out just how large the file is. This makes it difficult to manipulate and transport the data. Can someone please help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/384996/what-is-the-exact-format-and-size-of-image()-object?/) by [Tejas Rao](https://answers.ros.org/users/80574/tejas-rao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-24**:
The `rostopic --help` output may offer some guidance here:

> ```
>   --nostr               exclude string fields
> ```

```
  --noarr               exclude arrays
```

if you add `--noarr` to your `rostopic echo` command, you'll be able to see the header and other non-array fields.

> there is supposed to be a heading

probably a typo, but there is a `header` field. Not `heading`.

> This makes it difficult to manipulate and transport the data.

A general usability suggestion: if you can accept the OpenCV dependency, try to consume `sensor_msgs/Image` messages using [image_transport](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport) subscribers and convert messages to their OpenCV representation. That will make it much easier to work with them.

Working directly with the serialised form (in the form of `sensor_msgs/Image`) might not be the most efficient (from a usability perspective).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Tejas,

> exact size of Image.

a. first way to get size.
You can also get size from http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html by selecting this variable in your code.

```
uint32 height
uint32 width
```

Note: `rostopic echo /camera/image_raw` You are getting full `sensor_msgs/Image` data over here but each image has a huge matrix so you are not able to view the full message properly from your terminal.

b.  second way to get size.

Just check if you are getting the `camera_info` topic. You can get this by typing `rostopic list` then try to view information of that you will get all details like height, width and other details which you required.

```
rostopic echo  <camers-info-topic>#/camera/color/camera_info
```

> exact format

Have a look at this link you will get exact formate of an image message in ROS.

http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tejas Rao](https://answers.ros.org/users/80574/tejas-rao/) on 2021-08-25**:
Thanks, this helped a lot!